# Revolve $e^{-x^2}$ about the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, volume

I have to find the volume of the solid which is obtained by rotating the following region about the $x$-axis: 
$$y = e^{-x^2},\quad y=0,\quad x=-1,\quad x=1.$$

I am struggling to calculate the volume and I have come this far:$$V=\int_{-1}^{1}A(x)\text{d}x=\pi\int_{-1}^{1}\bigl(e^{-x^2}\bigr)^2\mathrm{d}x=\pi\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-2x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

Could anyone help me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this integral can be evaluated by means of elementary functions. It is some kind of error function and can only be approximated. Observe though that you can simplify a very little bit by taking advantage of the fact the function is even so $\;\int_{-1}^1=2\int_0^1\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integral is that bounded, you can make use of Taylor series for the integrand function:

$$e^{-2x^2} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-2x^2)^k}{k!}$$

thence substituting and taking the sum out of the integral sign, we have:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-2)^k}{k!}\int_{-1}^1 x^{2k}\ \text{d}x$$

Which is trivial.

After integrated you remain with:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-2)^k}{k!} \frac{(1 + (-1)^{2k})}{2k+1}$$

This series can be summed, and its sum is

$$\boxed{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{erf}(\sqrt{2})}$$

Where **erf** is a Special Function called the Error Function which is exactly what you would have found for that integral, being that integral a non trivial integral.

**More on Error Function**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: Great explanation, thank you so much!

Comment: @user297623 You're welcome! ^^